# Would vegans wear clothing or eat food made from human slavery?

Tags: veganism, is-it-vegan

Considering that vegans think that humans are animals, and vegans are against deriving benefit from animals, especially those who are abused who didn't agree to work for whoever is benefitting from them, then would a vegan be careful not to eat any food or use any products that are made through human slavery?

(For example some factories in China, and even products made in USA prisons where the workers don't have a choice to work or not)?

Comment: Products from USA prisons are not slave labor. The work they do there - whether in the kitchen, the laundry, the farm, the manufacturing facility - is all voluntary and is more like a skill development program. The first intent is they have a skill and are used to employment so they don't come back. The second intent is to give them something productive to do when they're in prison for years, decades or life. American prisoners are not at all like Uyghurs in China.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official rule book for being a vegan and certainly no police force who will prosecute you for claiming to be a vegan while breaking one of the rules.  So, a vegan who knowingly consumes the products of slavery is not impossible.

Nonetheless, I would be surprised to meet a vegan who knowingly and happily consumed the products of slavery.

Sadly, sometimes compromise is necessary to interact with society.  C.S.Cameron gives a good example of license plates.  Do you refrain from driving, drive illegally, or reluctantly accept it.

Some vegans (and many other groups) don't check the rules too hard.  I know some who check most products carefully but forget to check beer and wine.

Answer (score 0):

### Would vegans wear clothing or eat food made from human slavery?

How would the average Vegan, (or Ethical Vegetarian), know that their food or clothing is made using human slavery?

I have not seen a label on food or clothing stating "Made using Forced Labor".

Just because a shirt is cotton, does not mean that it was harvested by an Arkansas chain gang. Should we refuse to use license plates on our cars?

It is said that Jain are taught that karma is associated with unintentionally harming a being. Buddhists are taught that karma is only associated with intentional actions.

Comment: On one hand, I would agree with you. I don't think the average person doesn't read labels on clothes, food, or whatever. But if a person goes to the trouble of trying to determine whether or not Bayer Aspirin is "vegan," they're not average. Slave labor products simply are not the average vegan's hot button. To them, slave labor is just a milk cow.